# Unable to get calibrated predictions from logistic regression with imbalanced data

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

I'm trying to run some experiments and benchmark different calibration options and one thing I noticed is that the logistic regression output is not giving me calibrated predictions when my data is not balanced. This surprised me given that there is a lot of theoretical evidence why the output should be well calibrated. Could someone explain why I am seeing these results? You can find the code and the output below.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.calibration import calibration_curve
from sklearn.metrics import (brier_score_loss, precision_score, recall_score, roc_auc_score,
                             f1_score)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100000,
                           n_features=2,
                           n_informative=2,
                            n_redundant=0,
                            n_clusters_per_class = 1,
                            weights=[0.98, 0.02],
                            class_sep=1,
                           random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.5, stratify=y, random_state = 42)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

lr = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True)
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
gbm = GradientBoostingClassifier()

estimators = {
    'Logistic Regression': lr,
    'Random Forest': rf,
    'GBM': gbm
}

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.title("Two informative features", fontsize='small')
plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], marker='o', c=y_train,
            s=25, edgecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
def plot_calibration_curve(estimators, fig_index):
    """Plot calibration curve for est w/o and with calibration. """
    fig = plt.figure(fig_index, figsize=(10, 10))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=2)
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 1), (2, 0))

    ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], "k:", label="Perfectly calibrated")
    for name, clf in estimators.items():
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
        if hasattr(clf, "predict_proba"):
            prob_pos = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
        else:  # use decision function
            prob_pos = clf.decision_function(X_test)
            prob_pos = \
                (prob_pos - prob_pos.min()) / (prob_pos.max() - prob_pos.min())  
        clf_score = brier_score_loss(y_test, prob_pos, pos_label=y.max())

        print("%s:" % name)
        print("\tBrier: %1.3f" % (clf_score))
        print("\tPrecision: %1.3f" % precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
        print("\tRecall: %1.3f" % recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
        print("\tF1: %1.3f\n" % f1_score(y_test, y_pred))
        print("\tAUC: %1.3f\n" % roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred))

        fraction_of_positives, mean_predicted_value = \
            calibration_curve(y_test, prob_pos, n_bins=10)

        ax1.plot(mean_predicted_value, fraction_of_positives, "s-",
                 label="%s (%1.3f)" % (name, clf_score))

        ax2.hist(prob_pos, range=(0, 1), bins=10, label=name,
                 histtype="step", lw=2)

    ax1.set_ylabel("Fraction of positives")
    ax1.set_ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
    ax1.legend(loc="lower right")
    ax1.set_title('Calibration plots  (reliability curve)')

    ax2.set_xlabel("Mean predicted value")
    ax2.set_ylabel("Count")
    ax2.legend(loc="upper center", ncol=2)

    plt.tight_layout()

plot_calibration_curve(estimators, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect this is just noise in your plot. IE I suspect your data lies in 0 to 0.2 probability range, and the number of counts above eg .6 is too small for estimates of fraction of positives.

Comment: unfortunately, that was not the case. I ran the above with different random seeds and I got the same of the logistic curve in the calibration graph to be pretty much the same as described in the original question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point:  your (sklearn) plot doesn't have error bars. use eg pandas.cut to break prediction values into eg 0-5%, 5-10%....  How many points are there in the 0-5% prediction and in the 60-65% range.  I am claiming that maybe there are 1000 points in the 0-5% prediction range and therefore the true probability (y-value)  can be accurately estimate there whereas maybe only 10 points in the 60-65% range

Comment: you might want to superimpose the contour plot of the predict_proba output to get some insights. (and if possible determine the theoretical true value - by understanding what make_classification does)

Comment: @stasSajin Did you ever get to the bottom of this?